# Selenium webdriver en Python no tiene el output esperado

Tags: python

Estoy buscando sacar la información de la columna de codigos de una tabla que contiene informacion financiera de la siguiente manera:

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib import request, parse
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME  
desired_capabilities["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/racho/Documents/chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://www.etf.com/etfanalytics/etf-finder/?sfilters=eyJhc3NldENsYXNzIjp7ImluIjpbIkVxdWl0eSJdLCJvcmRlciI6MH0sInJlZ2lvbiI6eyJpbiI6WyJOb3J0aCBBbWVyaWNhIl0sIm9yZGVyIjoxfX0='
driver.get(url)
sleep(1)
try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "linkTickerName")))
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("linkTickerName")
    print(content)
except:
    print('Nope')
```

Sin embargo, no funciona. El output consiste de varias oraciones como la siguiente: selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7464e493a41a731abaeef7bb7fa334e", element="0.7040167854806081-1")

Comment: Hola María, deberías explicar que esperas obtener con más detalle, la salida es la esperada, una lista con los objetos `WebElement` encontrados... ¿Lo que buscas es obtener el texto (por ejemplo, de `<a class="linkTickerName" href="/SPY"> SPY </a>` obtener `SPY`)? ¿Obtener el  `href `? ¿Otra cosa?

Comment: Hola FJ, quiero obtener el texto, en este caso SPY.

Answer (score 1):

La salida es la esperada, el método `find_elements_by_class_name` retorna una lista (`list`) con los objetos de la clase [`selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) encontrados. Dicha clase es usada para representar cualquier elemento del DOM. Lo que ves dentro de la lista al imprimirla:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="a7464e493a41a731abaeef7bb7fa334e",element="0.7040167854806081-1")
```

solo es la representación de cada objeto contenido en la lista que muestra Python al imprimirla (el retorno de su método `__repr__`).

Dado que lo que realmente quieres es obtener el texto contenido en cada `<a>`, solo tienes que usar el atributo [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) del objeto:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME  
desired_capabilities["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/racho/Documents/chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://www.etf.com/etfanalytics/etf-finder/?sfilters=eyJhc3NldENsYXNzIjp7ImluIjpbIkVxdWl0eSJdLCJvcmRlciI6MH0sInJlZ2lvbiI6eyJpbiI6WyJOb3J0aCBBbWVyaWNhIl0sIm9yZGVyIjoxfX0='
driver.get(url)

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "linkTickerName")))
except TimeoutException:
    print('Nope')
else:
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("linkTickerName")
    codigos = [element.text for element in content]
    print(codigos)
```

La salida, si todo va bien, será una lista con el texto de cada elemento:

> ['SPY', 'IVV', 'VTI', 'VOO', 'VEA', 'QQQ', 'IEFA', 'AGG', 'EFA', 'VWO']

Comment: Gracias FJ, funcionó y todo quedó mas claro!