# Scraping pagina web devuelve vacio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

El problema que se me presenta es el siguiente:

Una página web, que muestra un tablero de estados por equipo (PC's)

La página web tiene una url, como esta, teniendo como variable el último número:

http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&equipo=22

Estoy tratando de raspar los datos de esta pagina sin conseguirlo aun, estoy usando este código de python:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&equipo=22/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Equipos

eq = soup.find_all('td', class_='ValorEquipo')'''<-- Esta es la clase que estoy tomando'''

equipos = list()

count = 0
for i in eq:

    if count < 20:
        equipos.append(i.text)
    else:
        break
    count +=1

print(eq)
```

Pero no me esta arrojando nada en la impresión y no me marca algún tipo de error, he inspeccionado la pagina para ver las clases de los controles y hacer la descarga de datos pero creo no estoy seleccionando las clases correctas, pueden ayudarme a ver que es lo que tengo mal.

Puntos a recalcar:
La página no tiene menús.
Los datos los muestra de forma tabular y se actualizan dinámicamente cada 5 min

Parte del código HTML:

```
//$('.table').append('<tr><td colspan="2">Maquina</td></tr>');
$('.table').append('<tr><td colspan="6" class="ValorEquipo">Maquina: ' + data.Maquina + '</td></tr>');
$('.table').append('<tr><td colspan="6">Empleado</td></tr>');
$('.table').append('<tr><td colspan="6" class="ValorEquipo">' + data.Empleado + '</td></tr>');
$('.table').append('<tr class="ValorEquipo"><td colspan="2">Output:' + data.Output + ' pcs</td><td colspan="2">Conteo Orden:' + data.ConteoOrden + '</td><td colspan="2">AjusteCount:' + data.ContAjust + '</td></tr>');
```

NOTA: No puedo instalar pluguins de terceros en los navegadores de la empresa.

Estoy tratando de adaptar el ejemplo de JSevilla, sin logralo aun.

Este es el codigo:

````
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
desired_capabilities["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jDani/Documents/Proyectos/chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&equipo=22/'
driver.get(url)

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ValorCorte")))
except TimeoutException:
    print('Nope')
else:
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ValorCorte")
    codigos = [element.text for element in content]
    print(codigos)```

Este es uno de los elementos de la pagina web que trato extraer:

    <tr class="ValorCorte">
    <td colspan="3">0.0</td> ==$0
    <td colspan="3">0.0</td>
</tr>

Me retorna el siguiente error:
C:\Users\jDani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/jDani/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/Scraping.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jDani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\jDani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\jDani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Otro punto importante es que la version de Chrome que tengo en el equipo es:
Version 72.0.3626.121 
Pero en la pagina de drivers de Chrome no aparece la version que tengo, por lo cual instale la version 73.0.3683.68.

Esto puede ser un problema?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

@FJSevilla

DS
````

Comment: Hola Jose, si el contenido es generado de forma dinámica por JavaScript, una vez cargada la página, requests  no te sirve (no puede ejecutar código JavaScript), necesitas una herramienta que pueda lidiar con ello como [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). En este caso, no obtendrías nada porque en el html que `get` obtiene no hay nada del contenido que quieres, este se genera después.Por ejemplo, una vez cargada la página y desde el cliente JavaScript se dedica a hacer peticiones AJAX  al servidor para traer los datos y generar la tabla dinámicamente. Un saludo.

Comment: Cómo puedo asegurarme que la página es dinámica por Javascript por el autoload que hace 5 min? Otra pregunta selenium en que plataforma lo usaría Java, c# o desarrollo web?

Comment: El que se recargue cada 5 minutos es una buena pista si, eso indica que hay código ejecutándose por debajo... Hay veces JS simplemente hace una petición que es invariante al servidor y este retorna un JSON con los datos para construir la tabla, podemos capturar la petición que hace JS al server (usando la extensión Postman de Chrome por ejemplo) y usarla directamente para hacer nosotros la petición via requests y usar ell JSON con los datos que retorna. Sin tener acceso a la página (entiendo que no puedas compartirla) es difícil dar una solución dada la gran variabilidad que hay.

Comment: Selenium tiene su binding para Python, el enlace que te dejo arriba es al paquete en PyPi. Te dejo el enlace a la última pregunta que respondí sobre Selenium en el que precisamente se obtienen datos de una tabla y te puede servir de referencia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/267884/15089. Selenium usa un navegador(driver) y permite emular a un usuario humano, hacer click, drop and drag, hovering, seleccionar algo, ingresar texto, etc además de poder obtener información de la página (scraping), esperar a que ocurran ciertas cosas (como que tu tablas se termine de cargar), etc.

Comment: @FJSevilla, La pagina como tal esta dentro de la intranet de la empresa y como comentas no puedo compartirla. Pero he visto las llamadas JSON que comentas, entonces crees que sea viable optar por el uso de Postman para llamar esos JSON desde Python?
E inclusive desde otra web , los datos que se muestran en la pagina son pocos 8 de forma tabular pero son campos calculados que viene de varias fuentes de informacion.

Comment: @FJSevilla Este es parte de JSON, digo parte porque es bastante informacion la que trae.
var data = JSON.parse('{"Calidad":0,"CalidadM":0,"Meta":4.00,"CalidadColor":"#00FF11"}');
        var error = "";
        var reloadSpan = 60 * 5;
        // var data = JSON.parse('{"Calidad":0,"CalidadM":0,"Meta":40.00,"CalidadColor":"#00FF11"}');
        $(document).ready(function ()
Si no es posible entonces optare por el uso de Selenium.

Comment: @FJSevilla, edite la pregunta con la adaptación de tu ejemplo pero me esta tirando error, que puede estar mal?

Comment: Hola Jose, en teoría debes especificar la ruta directa al ejecutable en sí, por ejemplo `/Users/jDani/Documents/Proyectos/chromedriver.exe`, depende de donde tengas el chromedriver **.exe**

Comment: @FJSevilla funciono ese era el problema.
Ahora una pregunta como puedo agregar los encabezados de esos valores y guardarlos en un csv?